# How to Pivot kind of output without any aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

i have table having many records like this.

```html
EventDateTime Event Desc  EventType
10:00 AM Any Description  Start
10:45 AM Any Description  Stop
11:00 AM Any Description  Start
11:25 AM Any Description  Stop
```

Basically i want time difference between both the event type.
So i want output like this.

```html
 EventDateTime EventDateTime Event_Desc     EventType EventType Diff
 10:00 AM     10:45 AM     Any Description Start     Stop     45 Min
```

Is it possible in SQL via PIVOT or any other way around?
I want in to display the same in crystal report.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following code and it seems to work for me. I tested it a little bit, hope it helps!

I used dense_rank to kind of simulate an ID for your events, so that I can identify a single event based on start time and end time, assuming though that consecutive records belong to the same event:

I created a new table, called table2 (temp table for me, to recreate your problem) where i stored the ranked values:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#table2') is not null drop table #table2
create table #table2 (eventdatetime time, [rank] int, descr varchar(199),eventtype varchar(150))

insert into #table2
select eventdatetime, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY eventtype ORDER BY eventdatetime asc) AS Rank, descr, eventtype 
from #table1  -- this is your table with events
order by eventdatetime

select t.eventdatetime start_time, t2.eventdatetime end_time,  t2.descr [event_descr], t.eventtype, t2.eventtype, datediff(mi, t.eventdatetime, t2.eventdatetime) [Diff]
from #table2 t2 join #table2 t on t2.rank = t.rank and t2.eventdatetime >  t.eventdatetime
order by t2.eventdatetime
```

[Here you can see the results I got from this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfjhu.png)

Comment: i had tried the same using view without modifying my existing schema and working fine...Thanks a lot..